# Effects while closing the Dialog box

Tags: jquery

Am using `Jquery Dialog` box. In this I have Submit and Close buttons. I want to put UI effects like [here](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) for the Close button.

My `Dialog box` code is below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#disableDivForm").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        position: 'center',
        height: 187,
        width: 472,
        modal: true,
        show: {
            effect: 'explode',
            duration: 400
        }
    });
    $('#body').show();
});​
```

There is a Close button inside `disableDivForm`. Code is below,

```
<div id="disableDivForm" name="disableDivForm">
    <input type="submit" id="cancelID" value="Close" onClick="return cancel()" class="but-bl2"/>
</div>

function cancel()
{
    document.disableForm.action=" - myAction goes here - "; 
    document.disableForm.method="POST";
    document.disableForm.submit(); 
}
```

I tried below code for achieving effects.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cancelID").click(function(){
       hide: {effect: 'explode', duration: 400}
    });
});
```

But, its not working. My Dialog box itself is not opening. No Java Script errors. I have placed code for .click function inside `<div id="disableDivForm">`

Comment: what you want hide with effect, dialog box or button ?

Comment: The last snippset seams not to be valid Javascript ; I mean the click handler inner code

Comment: @rajeshkakawat I want dialog box to be closed with effects.

Comment: @NaNisNoTNuLL Ya it seems not to be valid. Am not exactly getting how to use the `click` handler there. I tried different ways and ended up with above code which I feel that its near to the answer. Am exactly looking for the correct usage of `click` handler and `hide` effects.

Comment: check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/2vFCC/

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Works like charm. You can post that code as answer. Will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this fiddle out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vFCC/) , might be what you want. you can add hide effect in during initializing of dialog box

```
  $("#disableDivForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    position: 'center',
    height: 187,
    width: 472,
    modal: true,
    show: {
        effect: 'explode',
        duration: 400
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'explode',
        duration: 400
    }
});
```